How is Jehu a son of Jehoshaphat?
Jehu, called a son of Jehoshaphat in 2 Kings 9, is not in the list of sons in 2 Chronicles 21. Can someone help me fill in the gaps please?

2 Kings 9:2 - When you arrive, look for Jehu son of Jehoshaphat, the
son of Nimshi. Go in, get him away from his companions, and take him
to an inner room.
2 Kings 9:14 - Thus Jehu son of Jehoshaphat, the son of Nimshi,
conspired against Joram.
2 Chron 21:2 - Jehoram’s brothers, the sons of Jehoshaphat, were
Azariah, Jehiel, Zechariah, Azariah, Michael, and Shephatiah; these
were all sons of Jehoshaphat king of Israel


Have you considered the possibility that there was more than one Jehoshaphat? These theophoric names could be used by more than one person, and frequently were.

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

It appears that there are five people in the OT with the name "Jehoshaphat", namely:

Son of Ahilud and court official under David and Solomon, 2 Sam 8:16, 20:24, 1 Kings 4:3
A priest, 1 Chron 15:24, also called in Joshaphat in some versions
Son of Paruah of the tribe of Issachar, 1 Kings 4:17
Fourth king of Judah, the southern kingdom, who reigned for 25 years, and son of Asa, 1 Kings 22:41
Son of Nimshi and father of Jehu, 2 Kings 9:2, 14.

Thus, in Bible times, as in modern times, several people had the same name.

The confusion lies in 2 Chronicles 21:2 which states "these were all sons of Jehoshaphat king of Israel".
Jehoshaphat was not the King of Israel. He was the King of Judah, the Southern Kingdom whereas Jehu was the king of Israel, the Northern Kingdom. We are dealing with two completely different Jehoshaphats. Either there was a scribal error in putting "Israel" instead of "Judah", as the Septuagint states Judah in that verse or the author wanted to make a point in stating that Jehoshaphat was the true ruler of a unified monarchy of Israel (the term also used for the kingdom containing all 12 tribes) as Solomon and David were.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Jonathan. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Most scholars think King Jehoshaphat of Judah was not the (grand)father of
Jehu, and this is the reason Chronicles does not mention the fact. According to this hypothesis, Jehu's father was someone else with the same name. The Book of Kings recorded Jehu's bloodline because he became one of the kings of Israel. Chronicles downplays the importance of these kings, gives short shrift to Jehu's role. So it does not give details about his lineage.
For the author of the Book of Kings, Jehu's noble descent bolstered his claim to Israel's throne. Jehu was no mere usurper but was the son of well known family who had been appointed to his task by the prophets Elijah and Elisha. However, if we turn to the books of the prophets, we see that Hosea denounced Jehu for the massacre at Jezreel (2 Kings 10). This was the very thing that had brought him to the kingship, but Hosea declared that this bloody act was to be punished by bringing an end to his dynasty:
Hosea 1:4

Give him the name “Jezreel,” for in a little while I will punish the
house of Jehu for the bloodshed at Jezreel and bring to an end the
kingdom of the house of Israel.

The Book of Chronicles was  written centuries later. It focuses on Judah and gives relatively little attention to the history of the kings of Israel. It does not mention Jehu's prophetic commission and anointing, nor does it even mention the prophet Elisha. Its author must also have been aware that Jehu's kingdom was rejected because of the means by which he came to power.
Conclusion: King Jehoshaphat was probably a different person than Jehu's father, who had the same name. In any case we may speculate that the Book of Chronicles did not draw attention to Jehu's descent because it focused on the kings of Judah and was not interested in bolstering the northern kings' claim to authority.
